# What is so important about __name__ in python?

Tags: python, function, decorator

A `__name__` attribute is assigned to every python function. For example

```
>>> def f(*args, **kwargs):
...     pass
... 
>>> f.__name__
'f'
```

Now if we decorate this function with some decorator, we, essentially, return another function with different `__name__`

```
>>> def d(f):
...     def w(*args, **kwargs):
...         f(*args, **kwargs)
...     return w
... 
>>> f = d(f)
>>> f.__name__
'w'
```

It is highly recommended to use `wraps` from `functools` to decorate returned function, so that information like `__name__` and `__doc__` can be copied to original function.

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>> def d(f):
...     @wraps(f)
...     def w(*args, **kwargs):
...         f(*args, **kwargs)
...     return w
... 
>>> f = d(f)
>>> f.__name__
'f'
```

My question is that what are some serious troubles we can get into if we don't use `wraps` to copy information? Simply what is so important about `__name__` that it should be copied? Simple code, like my example, works fine if we don't use `wrap`.

One problem, I can think if, is serialization. For example, Django does not allow to use lambda expressions (they are nameless) to be used as default value for model fields.

Can somebody add some more problematic examples? Same question is for class decorators.

Comment: Hint: stack traces in exceptions…

Comment: API documentation is another example.  If you want the wrapper function to be documented and not the wrapped function it should inherit `__name__` and `__doc__` from the wrapped function.  It's just helpful for clarity and not strictly required by any means, unless you are specifically using code that does dispatching based on function names.

Comment: @Iguananaut I see, from both stack trace and documentation perspective, it is helpful at human level. No implications at machine level in compilation or execution.

Comment: Unless you're *programmatically* using the `__name__` for anything (which you legitimately may), no, it's just for the human.

Comment: The name isn't even so important for serialization necessarily (though it depends on what you mean by "serialization").  In the case of pickling for example you can pickle a named function that's defined at module-level, because the way the default pickling method for functions works is it just pickles the module name and function name, and then uses that to *import* the function when unpickling.  You can't easily do that with lambdas because the pickle would have to contain the code for the lambda itself (this *is* doable, and people have done it, but there are limitations).